# Running for loop terminal commands in Jupyter

Tags: python, linux, shell, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I know how to run command line in Jupyter : using !
For example, run an image file `2.jpg` on Python `process.py`

```
! python classify.py --filename /Users/images/2.jpg
```

Question is, how to process all files of a folder in iteration way (**idx**) in Jupyter cell, something like this:

```
for idx in range(10):
    ! python process.py --filename /Users/images/idx.jpg
```

Thanks

PS:
I tried **path** , did not work:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    cur_path = '/Users/images/'+str(i)+'.jpg'
    path = os.path.expanduser(cur_path)
    print(i,path)
    ! python process.py --filename path
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible hackish solution could be to use `eval` and let bash execute a string.

```
for idx in range(10):
    !eval {"python process.py --filename /Users/images/{image}.jpg".format(image=idx)}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Tried your method but get error like this: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: ` eval "python process.py --filename /Users/images/{image}.jpg".format(image=idx)'    Would you pls share some light ? I may did something wrong. Thanks

Comment: @BillAncalagontheblack There was an extra colon in the code that I had posted. Fixed now.

Comment: Just realized that ipython doesn't execute any python string after `!` by default. So, need to put the python part in between `{}`. Hoping it's fixed now. :fingers crossed:

Answer (score 23):

No need for subprocess or format. Something as simple as:

```
for idx in range(10):
    !python process.py --filename /Users/images/{idx}.jpg
```

works for me.

Answer (score 3):

The `!` simply indicates that the following code will be executed in the terminal.

So one option is just to code your statement in bash. It's not quite as easy as Python, but you can accomplish the same task like this:

```
! for file in /Users/images/*.jpg; do python process.py --filename /Users/images/$i; done
```

It's a for loop, but not a Python for loop.

Alternatively, consider going back to the source code of `process.py` and modifying it so that it will loop through the files in a directory. This can be done easily enough with the `os.listdir` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `glob` module and maybe `subprocess` instead of `!`. A simple `glob.glob("path/*.jpg")` will let you iterate over all pictures.

```
from glob import glob
from subprocess import check_call

for i in glob("/Users/images/*.jpg"):
    print("Processing:", i)
    check_call(["python", "process.py", "--filename", i], shell=False)
```

Using `!` or `eval` is never a good idea - the command may fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bash for loop in Colab notebook:

```
!for file in /Users/images/*.jpg; \
do python process.py --filename $file; \
done
```